# How to convert the system date format to dd/mm/yy in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to convert the system date to this format: `dd/mm/yy`

```
"2013-01-01 00:00:00.000" to "Score Calculation - 10/01/13".
```

My column contains the data:

```
1. DMS01A13010101
2. RMS01A13010201
3. 44
4. 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

What I want: if the record has `2013-01-01 00:00:00.000` in this format then only I change to `Score Caculation - dd/mm/yy`

My code is,

```
select 
   case 
      when (CHARINDEX(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, '-*') > 0 or 
            CHARINDEX(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, '*-') > 0) 
      then 'Score Calculation - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 1) 
    end checkthedate 
from 
    CSPGD30_TRACKING D30
```

Comment: How did you get day `10` since your date's day is `01`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
   SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),getdate(),101)  -- mm/dd/yyyy

   SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),getdate(),103)  -- dd/mm/yyyy
```

Check this . I am assuming D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X is of datetime datatype .
That is why i am using `CAST()` function to make it as an character expression because `CHARINDEX()` works on character expression.
Also I think there is no need of OR condition.

```
select case when CHARINDEX('-',cast(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X as varchar )) > 0 

then 'Score Calculation - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X, 103)
end
```

EDIT:

```
select case when CHARINDEX('-',D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X) > 0 
then 'Score Calculation - '+
CONVERT( VARCHAR(11), CAST(D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X as DATETIME) , 103)
end
```

See this link for conversion to other date formats: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: i want to conver the column name "D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X", where i can put that

Comment: Is 'D30.SPGD30_TRACKED_ADJUSTMENT_X' a datetime column ?

Comment: it's not working..what i want if "-" contains, then only i change the date format to this dd/mm/yy

Comment: This column contains the 1. "DMS01A13010101" , 2. "RMS01A13010201" , 3. "44" ,4. "2013-01-01 00:00:00.000"

Comment: ok , then no need of using CAST() in when clause but use CAST() in Then clause to convert column to datetime.

Comment: it is working but it shows the "Score Calculation - 2013-01-03 " this format..i need to conver this to "Score Calculation - 03/01/13"

Comment: thanks for your reply..it is working..thank you so much..and i accepted you answer too.

Comment: oh@m.hasan it would create another issue, the year is not converted to yy it is showing the 'yyyy'. so how can i convert the year as yy format

Answer (score 2):

The query below will result in `dd/mm/yy` format.

```
select  LEFT(convert(varchar(10), @date, 103),6) + Right(Year(@date)+ 1,2)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9304)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),getdate(),101) -- Converts to 'mm/dd/yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(11),getdate(),103) -- Converts to 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 3)
```

simply use this for dd/mm/yy
and this

```
select convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 1)
```

for mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 0):

The query below will result in dd-mmm-yy format.

```
select 
cast(DAY(getdate()) as varchar)+'-'+left(DATEname(m,getdate()),3)+'-'+  
Right(Year(getdate()),2)
```