# Convert Date format into DD/MMM/YYYY format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a query in `SQL`, I have to get a date in a format of `dd/mm/yy`

Example: `25/jun/2013`.

How can I `convert` it for `SQL server`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017300/how-to-convert-the-system-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy-in-sql-server-2008-r2?rq=1

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: i got the format as 25/06/2013 but what i need is 25/Jun/2013

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an exact match for the format you want. But you can get close with [`convert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and style `106`. Then, replace the spaces:

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')
```

Comment: Just to mention, code 103 directly gives requested date format with just numbers.

Answer (score 49):

There are already [multiple answers and formatting types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)  for SQL server 2008. But this method somewhat ambiguous and it would be difficult for you to remember the number with respect to Specific Date Format. That's why in next versions of SQL server there is better option.

### If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above versions, you should use  [Format() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

With culture option, you can specify date as per your viewers.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result'; 
  
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result';

US English Result Great Britain English Result  German Result Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result
----------------  ----------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------
10/1/2011         01/10/2011                    01.10.2011    2011/10/1

US English Result            Great Britain English Result  German Result                    Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result
---------------------------- ----------------------------- -----------------------------  ---------------------------------------
Saturday, October 01, 2011   01 October 2011               Samstag, 1. Oktober 2011        2011年10月1日
```

For OP's solution, we can use following format, which is already mentioned by @Martin Smith:

```
FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy', 'en-us')
```

Some sample date formats:

[image]

If you want more date formats of SQL server, you should visit:

1. [Custom Date and Time Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Standard Date and Time Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 31):

we can convert date into many formats like

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)
```

This returns `dd mon yyyy`

[More Here](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) This may help you

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer already gives the best solution using built in formatting methods in 2008.

It should be noted that the results returned is dependent on the language of the login however.

```
SET language Russian

SELECT replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')
```

Returns

```
06/апр/2015
```

at the time of writing.

For people coming across this question on more recent versions of SQL Server a method that avoids this issue - and the need to `REPLACE` is

```
FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/MMM/yyyy', 'en-us')
```

On 2005+ it would be possible to write a CLR UDF that accepted a DateTime, Formatting Pattern and Culture to simulate the same.

Answer (score 10):

Try using the below query.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6), ' ','/');
```

> **Result:** 20/Jun/13

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106), ' ','/');
```

> **Result:** 20/Jun/2013

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select convert(varchar,getdate(),100)
```

third parameter is format, range is from `100` to `114`, any one should work for you.

If you need date in `dd/mmm/yyyy` use this:

```
replace(convert(char(11),getdate(),113),' ','-')
```

Replace `getdate()` with your column name. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query-

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd/MMM/yy') as date
```

Hope, this query helps you.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select replace ( convert(varchar,getdate(),106),' ','/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying to manually enter the date to sql server 'date type' variable use this format while entering :

> `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Answer (score 0):

Just format after convert to a date (tested in SQL Server v.2017)

```
dd/mon/yyyy
Select Format(cast('25/jun/2013' as date),'dd/MMM/yyyy')

dd/mm/yyyy
Select Format(cast('25/jun/2013' as date),'dd/MM/yyyy')

dd/Month/yyyy
Select Format(cast('25/jun/2013' as date),'dd/MMMM/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get date and convert

```
Declare @Date as Date =Getdate()

Select Format(@Date,'dd/MM/yyyy') as [dd/MM/yyyy] // output: 22/10/2020
Select Format(@Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') as [dd-MM-yyyy] // output: 22-10-2020

//string date
Select Format(cast('25/jun/2013' as date),'dd/MM/yyyy') as StringtoDate // output: 25/06/2013
```

Source: [SQL server date format and converting it (Various examples)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/sql/sql-server-date-format-and-converting-it-various-examples/158)

Answer (score 0):

There are already very good answers available like:

```
select replace(convert(varchar,getdate(),106),' ','/')
```

But, I want to add a comprehensive list of codes for all the other formats:

[image]

---

Here is the the link:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/