# SQL Server 2014 Trouble with Convert Function

Tags: sql-server, function, date, datetime, sql-server-2014

For some reason the following queries return the same result, even though they shouldn't

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),101)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),102)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),103)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),104)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),105)-- Ad Infinitum (Tested up to 140)
```

Result

```
2014-10-07
```

Just in case today's date is 7-Oct-2014

- According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx
  there should only be 131 styles, IS the fact that I did NOT get an error with 132-140 related?

Technically I installed SQL Server 2014 in US-English and TRIED to change it using

```
set dateformat dmy
```

But I don't know whether it made a difference or not.

Did I screw up my install, should I repair it, uninstall and reinstall, format my machine altogether or is it not related.

First question posted, I believe I followed the rules, as I understood them, If I made a mistake, please do tell me.

Edit:

```
SELECT CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Has the same result.

Comment: OK - but you've not said what you're **looking** for - what output do you **want** ?? Did you have a look at the new [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function for SQL Server 2014?

Comment: I'm guessing you've misunderstood how dates (and datetimes) are stored in SQL Server (and pretty much any other programming language) - they don't have some kind of formatting information attached to them - they're just the date information. The *strings* that you're seeing are what happens when you ask a tool (such as management studio) to *show* you the date information. But don't confuse the string formatting that management studio is applying with the actual *data* that is stored in a `date` column or variable.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, my goal was to have ANY result other than the one I was getting, thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style only matters when the output type is a literal one, that is, `varchar` or `nvarchar`. What you are trying to do is converting datetime into date (result does not depend on style) and then allow the client application to display it however it likes.

In the example below, however, the differences are apparent:

```
select convert(varchar, cast(getdate() as date), 101);
select convert(varchar, cast(getdate() as date), 102);
select convert(varchar, cast(getdate() as date), 103);
select convert(varchar, cast(getdate() as date), 104);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VARCHAR instead of DATE in CONVERT function. Like below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),101)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),102)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),103)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),104)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),105)
```

Also, check out the below link for the same:
[Convert Date format into DD/MMM/YYYY format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server-2008)