# How to get only date be skipping time from sql server?

Tags: database

I want to show date in grid view but now there is time shows as well with date. 
I just enter simple query to access date column from table 
e.g i tried

```
string query="select date from attendance where month='October';
```

It returns date+time

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)