# I want to change date format to date time using substring

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have date format like 20151030
 I want to change it 30/10/2015
12:23:43 PM . Can anyone please advise on this.

Comment: Fast response will be much appreciated. I AM STUCK AT THIS.

Comment: Are you talking about query results?

Comment: Yes..i want to change date format to date time format in sql

Comment: What is the data type of your field?

Comment: It is simple number like 20151030

Comment: How is it stored in the database? As **what**?

Comment: 12:23:43 **PM**? If it's past 12, it's PM by definition. AM/PM is only added if you want hours < 12.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
select  CONVERT(varchar(25),   CONVERT(datetime, CAST(20151030 AS CHAR(10)), 113), 103)
```

The output would be `30/10/2015`

You can also visit [This URL](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) For a list of date formatting specifications.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server-2008) discusses on the similar lines about date formatting.