# Date format in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the date in this format `2017-02-03` and I want that my date should be in this format `01-Mar-2016` while making select command.

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are we talking about a DateTime column here?

Comment: A very similar Question which may help you: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server)

Comment: your value in your first part is ambiguous. Are you talking about `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO format) ?

Comment: If your dates are stored as dates, then they have no format. You *could* use something like `FORMAT(dateColumn, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')` **however**, formatting is almost always a job for the presentation layer, and not for SQL. Suppose you send this to presentation layer in this string format, and someone wants to sort the dates, only to find that `02-Dec-17` is coming out before `03-Jan-16`, but after `01-Feb-19`. Another consideration would be international users, by formatting on the client side you let their regional settings determine the date format, rather than your preference.

Comment: If your dates are not stored as dates, then you [have a bigger problem on your hand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). Fix that first.

Comment: it was in date format only...I got this from Format keyword

Answer (score 1):

Check this [website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4920b4f5-6855-4855-96a9-43f9365d63a0/change-sql-server-date-format?forum=netfxbcl). This will be helpful.

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106),' ','-')
```

What is done here is: First convert it into '01 Mar 2016' and then replace white spaces(' ') with '-'. Which will give desired output as '01-Mar-2016'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function where you can specify .NET format string

For instance for current date

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Also you can specify culture here if needed

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'en-US');
```

---

If you dates are stored as string you'd better fix this but you can just [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) them instead. I.e.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2017-10-11' AS date), 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```