# SQL date convert from 20 Dec 2016 to 20 December 2016

Tags: sql

current SQL to get 20 Dec 2016 is:
Convert(char(11), getdate(), 13) DATE,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the system date format to dd/mm/yy in SQL Server 2008 R2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017300/how-to-convert-the-system-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT FORMAT(cast('20 DEC 2016' as date),'dd MMMM yyyy')`

Comment: Or you want to get current date as the desired format: SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd MMMM yyyy')

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!