# Change the date format in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2014

I want to change the date format for one of my column in database named Equipment. Anyone know how to change it in SQL Server 2014? The date format now is yyyy-mm-dd, i want to change to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Date format into DD/MMM/YYYY format in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017300/how-to-convert-the-system-date-format-to-dd-mm-yy-in-sql-server-2008-r2?rq=1